# Android and other OS at the same time

Tags: windows-mobile, dual-boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I install Android on my non-Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6849/can-i-install-android-on-my-non-android-device)

Is it possible to have Android 2.2 as well as say Windows 7 Mobile on my smartphone?
Any idea how that can be done?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe a way has been found to dual-boot.  However, the HTC Desire Z (Android) and the HTC HD2 (Windows Mobile 7) are basically the same phone, so I'm sure a dedicated developer could make it work for those.  Windows Phone 7 doesn't work on any phone the way Windows works on any PC, and Android is mostly the same.

N.B. Something called "Gen.Y DualBOOT" allowed for Android and Windows Mobile 6 to run on the same phone, but I don't believe it has been updated for WP7.  There's a netbook that [does it, but not very well](http://mobile.slashdot.org/story/09/10/23/1628237/Android--Windows-7-Dual-Boot-Netbook-Disappoints).

Comment: Thanks, Matthew. I read about Gen.Y DualBOOT and some others, but it seems it's possible to do if you have Windows 7 Mobile installed then getting Android and rarely the other way around. I'll give it a bit more time to see if someone has found a way, prefferably a "clean" way that doesn't require messing up the current Android installation or that will stop working once 2.3 arrives etc.

Comment: Yep, Android on a WP7 device is more likely to work.  Good luck!